# Doubt regarding equation for orbits of particles in Schwarzschild geometry

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, potential-energy

In Carroll's textbook "Spacetime and Geometry (page 208)," the equation for the orbits of particles in Schwarzschild geometry is written as
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dr}{d\lambda}\right)^2+V(r)=\mathscr{E}$$
where
$$V(r)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{GM}{r}+\frac{L^2}{2r^2}-\frac{GML^2}{r^3}$$
and
$$\mathscr{E}=\frac{E^2}{2}$$

The is the equation of a classical particle of unit mass and energy $\mathscr{E}$ moving in a one-dimensional potential $V(r)$.

The confusion (as mentioned in the text):

"The conserved energy per unit mass is E, but the effective potential for the coordinate r responds to $\mathscr{E}=E^2/2$."

**Question:**

What does it mean for the particle to have energy $\mathscr{E}$ rather than $E$, since the energy per unit mass is actually $E$?

Can we somehow prove that the particle (with energy per unit mass $E$) have energy $\mathscr{E}=E^2/2$ when it moves in the potential $V(r)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a differential equation $f(\dot E, E, r)=0$ which describes the evolution of the energy $E$ of a system, and fortunately you can reformulate it as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\dot E^2+V(E)=r
$$
then, you can call $\frac{1}{2}\dot E^2$ *effective* kinetic energy, $V(E)$ -- *effective* potential and $r$ *effective* total energy.

You do not need to prove anything, these come from the similarity to the equation of single particle.